# What's the reason why some TeX files compile fine on TeXworks but others don't?

Tags: tex-general

For example, when I download the `ShowcaseCircular.tex` file from [here](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/#text), I can see it previewed on the PDF viewer. But when I try `pp.tex`, I get some kind of error on TeXworks. Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several format to compile the LaTeX code.
`ShowcaseCircular.tex` compiles with `pdflatex`,
while `pp.tex` compiles with `context`.
You have to choose the appropriate compilation format for the right TeX file.